# EMR Spark job using less executors than nodes in the cluster

Tags: apache-spark, emr

I have set up a testing cluster consisting of 1 m4large driver and 3 m4large nodes. Without adding any extra configuration arguments to `spark-submit` I wanted to test this cluster configuration. However, when I check in the Spark UI I can see that my Spark job only uses 2 executors and I also notice in Ganglia that one node is barely doing anything (like it's not used at all).

What can I do to make sure that all nodes are getting tasks to complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spark-submit` doesn't use the whole cluster unless you specify the number of executors, `executor-core` and `executor-memory`. By default it uses the configuration specified in the spark default configuration. You can see the default config in the `spark-defaults.conf` file inside the spark installation directory.

Now by default spark-submit uses 2 executors 512MB memory in the executor. So if you want the whole cluster please use spark-submit command with specifying executor-core and executor-memory.

You can find the examples [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

Comment: So I am trying to set these to different values, but notice no change in amount of executors used nor execution time. I heard EMR changes the spark defaults itself upon cluster creation, so maybe that is what is done? I am still not sure why it does not use all executors (the 3 nodes) when running my job?

Comment: Why are you changing the default config? You can specify the executor number in the command line too. Did you try to do that ?

Comment: Oh sorry my message wasn't clear. I am not changing the default config. I specify it with the -- options on spark-submit, however I see no change in the Spark UI.

Comment: Here is one of the examples I tried: spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 5500m --num-executors 3 --executor-cores 4 --class ... However only driver + 2 executors was used, and if i specified num-executors to 4, the program still run but no change.

Comment: Do you have multiple Yarn queue in the cluster ? If your default queue has less capacity then your job will run with less footprint. The command-line you are using is correct.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea, I am currently just using standard EMR configurations while not changing anything.